# EF -> RIA Services -> Silverlight, Can I show validation error messages but still Save changes

Tags: silverlight, validation, data-annotations, wcf-ria-services

I am using Entity Framework 4.0, RIA Services, and Silverlight 4.0.  I need the user to be able to save any changes regardless if they are correct or incomplete.  To do this I had to make a lot of fields in the database nullable.  I still want to be able to show validation error messages in the Silverlight client to the user.  What I would like to do is use DataAnnotations to attribute the entities metadata in Ria Services to get the nice validation error messages on the client but I need the user to be able to save even if it breaks validation.  Is this possible?  How would I go about implementing this?

Thanks,
Evan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Silverlight there is no such thing as warnings-only Data Annotation Validators.  In ASP.NET you could get your intended outcome using a CustomValidator that was simply client-side JavaScript, but no such equivalent is present in Silverlight.  Your best bet is to program this logic into the form itself or create a custom control which allows you to decorate an existing control much in the way that the ToolTipService works.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for but I appreciate you giving it to me.  I guess I'll just have to write a bunch of messy validation code in each form.  Thanks

Comment: @Evan I recommend you look at creating your own control which you can decorate other controls with much like you do with the ToolTipService.  See this article for how to add attached properties to existing controls as a starting point: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Attached-Properties-in-Silverlight.aspx  It will be the easiest approach to maintain.